# visual studio 11 javascript metro app deployment error

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, microsoft-metro

i am using the windows developer preview with the visual studio 11, when i create  a blank javascript project and try to debug it , i got the following deployment error:

```
Error   1   Error DEP0700 : Registration of the application from layout "C:\Users\dassio\AppxLayouts\164051d0-bdaf-4ccc-b155-6fee67bc3a53VS.Debug.AnyCPU.dassio" failed for the following reason (please check the event viewer for possible additional details):   Camera
Error   2   [VisualElements] The notifications helper failed with error : 0x80070490 [ErrorCode]    Camera
```

what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Package Identity (open the manifest, go to the package tab and modify the identity).

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/winappswithcsharp/thread/e5cd8997-d175-49f0-830e-78788ddd2a6b

Hope that helps.